# Value Change Listener not firing

Tags: java, data-binding, jface

I'm trying to implement JFace databinding on a custom (non swt non JFACE) date time widget. The widget is made from scratch by a third party and we use it in our application.

I'm trying to add databinding to it, and it almost works, in the sense that when I create the binding, the "fillInitialValue" method does manage to put the correct date into the widget, but the value change listener is not working (breakpoint within it, not executing at all).

In the ValueBinding class (org.eclipse.core.databinding) it does add the listener

```
target.addValueChangeListener(targetChangeListener);
```

where the target is my `AbstractObservableValue` implementation (DateChooserObserver), and the listener is the default one

```
private IValueChangeListener targetChangeListener = new IValueChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void handleValueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        if (!updatingTarget
                && !Util.equals(event.diff.getOldValue(), event.diff
                        .getNewValue())) {
            doUpdate(target, model, targetToModel, false, false);
        }
    }
};
```

This is my target observer:

```
public class DateChooserObserver extends AbstractObservableValue<Date> {

    private DateChooserCombo widget;

    public DateChooserObserver(DateChooserCombo widget) {
        super();
        this.widget = widget;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueType() {
        return Date.class;
    }

    @Override
    protected Date doGetValue() {
        return widget.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doSetValue(Date value) {
        widget.setValue(value);
    }

}
```

The only thing I can think of is that I might need to put a value change observer (somehow) on the actual date field and not the widget, but I'm not sure how.

I have no idea why it's not working. Of the two converters that I do have (convert attribute to widget and widget to attribute) both fire initially, but, like I said, the listener is not detecting changes in the `java.util.date` field of the widget (or the widget itself, I don't know) and the *convert widget to attribute* is not being executed when I select a new date.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid being [DenverCoder9](https://xkcd.com/979/), I'll submit my solution on all of this.

First thing: I didn't have full access to the widget we are using, so I couldn't make a "correct" implementation, but I did find a workaround:

The AbstractObservableValue class has a `addValueChangeListener(ValueChangeListener listener)` method that you can override. That gives you direct access to the listener, and you can forcibly activate it's "handleEvent" method.

I don't have the actual code on me right now, I hope I don't forget to update this answer next monday, but the solution was something like this:

```
public class DateChooserObserver extends AbstractObservableValue<Date> {

    ...

    @Override
    public void setValueChangeListener(ValueChangeListener listener) {
        super.setValueChangeListener(listener);
        widget.getText().addModifyListener(e -> {
            listener.handleEvent(new ValueChangeEvent(this, getDummyDiff();
        });
    }

    // returns a diff with different dates to always evaluate true in doUpdate()
    public ValueDiff<Date> getDummyDiff() {
        return new ValueDiff() {

            @Override
            public Date getOldValue() {
                return new Date(1,1,1);
            }

            @Override
            public Date getNewValue() {
                return new Date(1,1,2);
            }
        }

    }
```

An upgrade would be to give the actual old / new dates in the diff, since it tries to not do the update if the dates haven't changed, but I had no way of obtaining them, so an "always true" diff was my only solution.

TL;DR, there's a listener, listener does stuff, but if you don't have a compatible widget or access to the internal workings of the widget, you need to force that listener's handle event.

P.S. I'm not sure if `doUpdate()` is the name of the method in databinding, just a placeholder, has little relevance any way.